# Shortest possible selector for multiple elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply one CSS rule for multiple selectors. like this:

```
.btn-group.pull-right.with_space .btn + .btn, .btn-group.pull-right.with_space i + i{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Now my question is, if there's a shorter way to do it. (since the parent elements are the same for both selectors, and the different is only in the last child).

Comment: Not unless you want to use SASS, LESS, or some other CSS pre-processor. Edit: Or, add a common class to the elements you are targeting.

Comment: You could check if any one of the classes is unique enough, then you could just write (for example) `with_space .btn + .btn, .with_space i + i`. And/or, if it's always the second child in the container, `.btn-group.pull-right.with_space :nth-child(2)`. I agree with @Quantastical though, using a class in the children is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, if you choose to use a CSS pre-processor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you can do nested selectors, like so:

```
/* SASS example */
.btn-group.pull-right.with_space {
  i + i, .btn + .btn {
     /* ... */
  }
}
```

After compiling, the resulting CSS will be similar to what you had already written.

Sometimes, it might be better to add a common class to the elements that are sharing styles. So, in your `.btn + .btn` and `i + i` elements, add a class, such as `btn_and_i`, so you can target them with a single selector:

```
/* CSS example */
.btn_and_i {
   /* ... */
}
```

If you're hell-bent on making this the "shortest" selector possible, then add a single-character class to the targeted elements, such as `"a"`.

```
.a {
  /* ... */
}
```